# Can't install AMD graphics card

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

For the life of me I cannot work out how to properly install the drivers for an AMD graphics card. I have an Acer laptop with a Radeon HD 6550m in it.

I go to the official AMD support site (after a clean Windows 7 64 bit install), select notebook graphics, Radeon HD series, Radeon HD 6xxxM series, Windows 7 64 bit then finally display results.

I see 'Catalyst Software Suite' available for download (1.1MB file size) revision 11.9. I download it and install it and then BOOOOOM, it says 'AMD Catalyst Mobility cannot be downloaded due to incompatible hardware/software on your computer. The version of your graphics adapter is not supported.'

Umm... what? I know for sure I have a HD 6550M as it says so in device manager on my Windows 7.

So then I try clicking on the 'individual download' tab on the amd website and find something called 'Catalyst Control Center'. File size 87mb, revision number 11.9. I install it with express settings but it says: 'installation complete warnings occurred during the installation.' Here is the log:

http://pastebin.com/Te7L005g

I did not truncate that, that is the entire log file even after refreshing my browser several times.

So after that install nothing has changed, the screen didn't even flash during install. I still do not have a functioning graphics card. I can't even view my desktop at proper screen resolution for my 14inch screen.

So what is going on here? What is the correct way to install this card? What is the difference between 'Catalyst Software Suite' and 'Catalyst Control Center' and which am I supposed to download and install?

What a nightmare... I'd just like to be able to enjoy some Starcraft 2 (so hopefully I can get absolutely most up to date driver for this card.)

PS. Here is a screenshot of my laptop after my futile attempts:

http://imagebin.org/181230

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know for a fact that with my HP laptop, no AMD driver download works - you have to get it  directly from the HP website... and it is an outdated rubbish version.

Unfortunately, I don't think AMD have changed, and, the catalyst download is mainly for people  who have an unlocked laptop / one that allows you to install whatever drivers you want.

If this is the case, I recommend you take a look at [LaptopVideo2Go Forums](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/forum/158-amdati/) - They mainly deal with Nvidia, but, you may have some luck looking around the forums.

Comment: +1  Acer drivers will be the choice here.  Often vendor like AMD sells chipset and Acer (or others) make changes.  nVidia site even warns not to use drivers from that site on Dell and others.  Only drivers from the laptop maker.

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst Control centre consists of the following,

1. Catalyst display Drivers(This is necessary for graphics card to work  )
2. Catalyst control Panel   (This is Optional but you it needs for advanced users,we can configure the graphics card settings,resolution,Anti-aliasing etc.,)
3. Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1

Now Reinstall again , while running the application i request you to run as administrator ,
then during the installation Choose Custom settings instead of Express settings,

Now you will see the details of installed drivers and details about your required software whether it is need to upgrade etc.,Tick the check box and stay behind (don't install any other software during installation). New Catalyst drivers nowadays not flickering our desktop nowadays during installation(For my Computer).

Reboot now while prompting,don't postpone.That's it.

After that change your desktop resolution manually through windows screen resolution option by right clicking desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using these drivers, for AMD Radeon HD 6770M cards.
Be warned though, this NULLIFIES the Catalyst Control Center, and Switchable Graphics.

http://www2.ati.com/DRIVERS/mobile/12-3_mobility_vista_win7_64_dd_ccc.exe

Kudos.
-swaschan